# Validating an AASA file

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, aasa

The 2 following files are supposed to be the same thing (an AASA file), the difference being that the second is meant for more recent versions of iOS.

But according to https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ this first file is OK:

```
   {
     "applinks": {
         "apps": [],
         "details": [
              {
           "appID": "1234567.mydomain.soft.MyApp",
           "paths": ["*"]
              }
          ]
      },
      "webcredentials": {
         "apps": ["1234567.mydomain.soft.MyApp"]
      }
   }
```

while this other one is invalid:

```
   {
     "applinks": {
         "details": [
              {
                "appIDs": [ "1234567.mydomain.soft.MyApp" ],
                "components": [
                  {
                     "/": "/*",
                     "comment": "Matches any URL"
                  }
                ]
              }
          ]
      },
      "webcredentials": {
         "apps": [ "1234567.mydomain.soft.MyApp" ]
      }
   }
```

Can someone tell me why the second has a problem?

I see this message:

```
 -- This domain's AASA was pulled, but the JSON format seems Invalid.
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue do have any solution to fix?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353296/universal-links-not-working-on-a-swiftui-app

Comment: After setting the ContentType header to the AASA file, worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's the root cause or not, but I see some white spaces in your appIDs. Remove those spaces may help you.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I checked, but these spaces did not exist in the original, it was just some kind of mistype when making the post. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think you may need to keep the old fields to support older os versions and pass that validation tool, like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60435725/3867033

Comment: And I think it's better to know exactly what the iOS is saying about your AASA by checking logs in the Console app in the first app startup.

Comment: It seems you last comment is interesting, but I don't see anything at all. So I may already have a problem here. Where, when and what am I supposed to see? I have never used universal links before so I may be missing some very basic detail.

Comment: As far as know, iOS will fetch your AASA right after you install your app. So be sure to open the Console app before installing the app. If you've already installed the app, you may want to delete it first.

Comment: Like this: https://i.imgur.com/er2HWs3.png
If the system failed to understand your file, there will be some suggestions for you there.

Comment: OK. I have started the console app as you suggest, before installing the app (of course, deleting it first), but I still don't see anything related to the AASA file. Because I didn't do the right thing about AASA/Universal-Links, or because I am not familiar with the console app and just don't know how to properly use it; I don't know.

Comment: I think you've already done it but just want to make sure that have you configured your universal links for your project by adding associated domain capabilities?

And in the Console app, you have to select your device. Make sure that you are seeing the proper device which you are using for test.

Comment: Yes I have configured an Associated Domain.
"applinks:example.net"

Comment: Are you seeing the proper device on the Console app?

Comment: In the Console App I selected my iPhone as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about this situation.

Comment: That's OK, thanks for you help anyway. I need to digg a bit more.