# Universal Links not working on a SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-universal-links

I am working on a little app using `SwiftUI` and `CoreLocation`.
It is starting to behave the way I want. But at this point, I am having difficuties to integrate `Universal Links`.

In Xcode (version 11.6), I have added the Associated Domain:

```
applinks:mydomain.example.net
```

I have also checked: `Associated Domains` (not MDM Managed Associated Domains) in the `App Identifier` (On the Developper Portal).

On my website (https://mydomain.example.net) I have placed the *apple-app-site-association* file in *.well-known/* under the root directory.

This is the shape of the file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
           {
    "appID": "1122334455.my.app.bundle.MyApp",
    "paths": ["*"]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": ["1122334455.my.app.bundle.MyApp"]
   }
}
```

And in the *SceneDelegate.swift* file, I have added this method:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    print(#function)
    // TESTING-CODE
    ... change app-background to RED!
}
```

Thinking it should be called when pointing Safari to https://mydomain.example.net/somefile, on a device where the app is installed.

But it never seems to be called, and my `Universal Links` experiment is not working.

I have tried both launching the app on my device from Xcode and launching the app on my device after it has been uploaded to TestFlight. Both failed; I must be missing something, maybe basic, but I just don't know.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to finding the solution to my problem?

Comment: I have taken a look at the post; unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. At least for what I have tried at this point.

Comment: How are you "pointing Safari" to that URL?  It sounds like you're entering it into the URL bar, in which case the system won't check if it's a universal link; it'll assume you wanted to go there in your browser.

Try opening the Notes app and typing your url in there, then when the app formats it as a link, tap on it.

Comment: @Jamie A; Indeed, I was entering the address into the URL bar of Safari.
Thinking Safari would do the necessary check. Nevertheless if I do as you suggest, going through the Notes app, when I tap the link it still opens Safari and not my app. If I try to keep an eye on what is going on inside the app (while I tap the link), by plugging the device into my computer and look in the Xcode debugging console what is happening, I see no whatsoever trace of activity linked to my opening the link. (Nothing happens)

Comment: Does your app open and it just doesn't do what you want or is it not opening at all?  Have you tried double checking your server-side setup with a validator like https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool or https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: My app just didn't open at all. I just found out what the issue was not long ago. When writing : "appID": "1122334455.my.app.bundle.MyApp". I was using my appID, but something (provisioning profile) made me doubt; I had to use my teamID instead. It is now working. Maybe a stupid mistake? Thank you for your help.