# apple-app-site-association - only allow some paths to be opened in app and disallow everything else

Tags: ios-universal-links, aasa

I'm struggling to figure this one out... So we have a web app with the following URL structure:

`/city/posttype/slug`

We want to implement dynamic linking, but we only want to open certain post types in the app, nothing else.

So for example these should link to the app:

- `/new-york/posttypeA/slug`
- `/new-york/posttypeB/slug`
- `/new-york/posttypeC/slug`

Meanwhile, for example, these should not be opened in the app:

- `/new-york/posttypeD/slug`
- `/new-york`
- `/`

Here is our AASA file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "OUR_APP_ID",
        "paths": [
          {
            "/": "/*/posttypeA/*",
            "comment": "matches all posttypeA"
          },
          {
            "/": "/*/posttypeB/*",
            "comment": "matches all posttypeB"
          },
          {
            "/": "/*/posttypeC/*",
            "comment": "matches all posttypeC"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But our iOS app still wants to handle all links from our website. As I've read any time I do a change to our AASA file I need to reinstall the iOS app which I did but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh jeez I've actually mixed up pre-iOS13 format with the new format and that was the reason it was not working... This comment helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232752/851490